# Why are freelancers not present at working position?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm quite new at Stack Overflow and just today updated my working position as suggested.

I work as a [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) freelancer developer, and I've found `Freelance` option to choose, but in my profile it looks quite ugly:

> Senior Development Engineer **at** Freelance

I can imagine, a wide number of Stack Overflow users work **as** freelancers, not really **at** a company called `Freelance`.

- Can a *special* category for this case be created?
- Or maybe add a bit more freedom in the moment of choosing the conjunction?

The result I expected was something like

> Senior Development Engineer **as** freelance**r**

Comment: Funnily, every job and other major site I know gets this as wrong, leading to insanities like `Software Development Engineer at self` and such

Comment: Maybe SE can start Freelance, Inc.? Might be cheaper then the dev hours needed to fix this ...

Comment: @rene There is no need of SE or SO, you can create your own (ckeck my profile now) but this does not fix the situation, and I think adding a Exception creating a special case for freelancers compared to benefits for all who are here in same position will be worth enough

Comment: I would say that the value from adding this compared to the value from addressing other features/bugs is pretty low. It's a silly thing that everywhere gets wrong and no hiring manager would lost sleep over it unless your resume says that you coded that part of the site that they are hiring from.

Comment: "Senior Development Engineer as freelancer" sounds just as wrong. If you're going to fiddle with this, make it say "Freelance Senior Development Engineer". Of course, it's kind of silly to give yourself an Official Sounding Title when you're working as a freelancer. You're the senior over yourself?

Comment: I think this is a good idea. I'll make sure to bring it up with the team next week

Comment: You can just put the whole title (e.g. `Freelance Senior Development Engineer`) into the field before `at` (`Current Position`). http://i.stack.imgur.com/khePE.png

Comment: So... it you're a "freelancer" you can make up your own title?

Comment: @CodyGray `You're the senior over yourself?` actually, yeah. I've had to really kick my ass many times during my career. A couple times I was on the verge of firing myself!

Comment: Isn't it possible to leave the company empty? If so, you can just call yourself a 'Freelance Senior Development Engineer', and that's it. -edit- I think this is exactly what @CharlotteDunois meant. XD

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for the hard laugh XD

Comment: You could write it as `Freelance Java Developer at Your Name, S.P.` if you're a Sole Proprietor (which, in the United States, you are by default if you're doing business without any other form of company) or `Freelance Sr. Developer at Your Own Company Name, L.L.C.`, etc. substituting in the actual type of business entity you use for freelancing.

Comment: No doubt for spending too much time on Stack Overflow, @pekka!

Comment: @GolezTrol `Isn't it possible to leave the company empty?` Yes, yes it is, with so many employers that's what happens. That's why we want to go freelance in the first place.

Comment: @CodyGray `work as freelancer != work alone`, at least in my case... about phrasing, I'm not a native English speaker, so it can be wrong for sure, suggestions are very welcome

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you're totally right! many thanks!

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Would you mind adding that advice below as an answer?

Comment: @Ana Been there, done that.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Cheers!

Comment: @Ana will SE accept the workaround as a solution? Benjamin said *I'll make sure to bring it up with the team next week*. If yes I will mark Charlotte's answer as accepted or will wait otherwise `:)` thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can just put the whole title (e.g. `Freelance Senior Development Engineer`) into the field `Current Position` (before `at`) and leave the `Company Name` field empty. This way `at [Company Name]` won't appear in your profile.
[image]

If you've done that, it will look like this in your profile:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For all ye freelancers out there, you can choose to do this. You clearly <3 code, so you can just say so. I clearly don't work, I'm not getting any university degree anytime soon, so I had only one option left:

[image: I Just <3 Code]

That text box will let you say anything you'd like, without any added words or constraints. If you want, you can change that text to *Senior Development Engineer as Freelancer" or whatever you'd like.

Of course, if there is any functionality associated with selecting "Work" or "School," you'd likely lose that, but I'm not aware of anything associated with those options.

Comment: Now your profile is a contradiction. First it says "human developer," then later on, it says "I made myself a monkey."

Comment: @CodyGray Didn't you realize? Those darn ---modraters--- monkeys are going to take over the entire Stack Exchange network... And then the entire world!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback! The Careers section of the profile is rather redundant as a result of Developer Story. Developer Story is now the place to add your professional title and work history. It has single title field which would handle your freelancer example better.

We have plans to remove the Career section from the profile and also update the signup form to get new users filling in their Developer Story rather than this section.

Given the workaround of not providing a company name or using the "Just <3 Code" option (suggested by Charlotte Dunois and Zizouz212), and the plans to remove the section in favour of Developer Story, it's not something we're going to add right now.